# My computer is using too much memory

Tags: memory, windows-11

I have 8gb of ram on my computer and the task manager shows that I am using 1.5 gb of memory but if I look in the percentage of memory used it shows 70% (out of 8gb).
My computer slows down too.
[image: task manager's users tab (extra characters)]

[rammap shows that 4gb are being used while in the same time the task manager showed around 7gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2vKl.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to images, rather include the images directly in the question. You can edit your question to make the modification.

Comment: 70% of RAM usage is perfectly normal, and this can not slow down your computer.

Comment: For some reason it only lets me upload images as links.

Comment: Go to details tab and sort by username. You can see all the system memory usage there and potentially see if there is anything running you do not expect to be running. This does seem about normal, though.

Comment: @PierU New contributors cannot embed images. I believe it's a precaution against porn, explicit or illegal content and such. We routinely review images and embed them if they are OK. For a new contributor, posting a link to an image is the right way to have the image embedded eventually.

Comment: Please provide RAMMap task manager is basically pointless to diagnose potential memory usage issues.

Comment: @Narzard I added a photo of the users tab, this is the only user active and it is only taking 1.5 gb of memory, why would the task manager say 5.6 gb are being used?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski OK, I didn't know!

Comment: 1.5GB is the memory occupation of the processes owned by the particular user (you). This does not count all the processes launched by the OS (Windows). Plus, all modern OS use the available RAM as a file cache: this is not a problem, as the RAM used for caching can be instantaneously free'd by the OS if needed.

Comment: @PierU but does windows occupy 4 gb? and when I am trying to launch something a little more resource heavy my computer slows down and the memory is completely occupied even though I am only using 4 gb with my processes.

Comment: You're only seeing the Windows disk cache in action.

Comment: If you want to see the processes that the most occupy the RAM, you have to select the "processes" tab in the task manager (and possibly to click on "more details" on this tab, if it shows up), then click on the "Memory" field to sort the processes by increasing order of RAM occupation. Also, the "Performance" tab (choosing "Memory" on the left) can give additional informations. This is for Windows 10, I am not sure if the Task Manager is exactly the same on Windows 11.

Comment: I already looked at the performance tab and it says I am using 6.5 gb but my processes are only taking 3 gb, it says that 1.5 gb are in cache too.

Comment: *"...but my processes are only taking 3 gb..."* : how do you know that?

Comment: I summed all the processes that are shown by the task manager.

Comment: Not all the processes appear in the task manager list... Besides, RAMMAp show about 7GB occupied, if I interpret it correctly. You should look at the memory occupation right after a reboot, before you do anything else. And about the slowdowns: is the system disk a SSD, or a HDD?

Comment: ssd, the problem is still happening even after a clean boot

Comment: Maybe you have too many resident tools installed (the ones that start at boot time or when opening the session), which eat your resources? For instance do you have a third party antivirus?

Comment: I don't, and I barely have any programs open at startup